# Background Jobs in C (implementing & in a toy shell)

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I want to make it so when a user attaches a - after a command it will be executed in the background. For some reason if I execute a command normally it will wait, then if I execute a command in the background it will work but then if I execute a command normally it won't wait for it. I am sure I am just doing something small-ish wrong. Any ideas:

```
void executeSystemCommand(char *strippedCommand, char *background, int argc, char **args) {
    char pathToExecute[80];


    // Check if command will be executed in the background
    int shellArgs;
    bool bg; 
    if (!strcmp(background, "-")) {
        bg = true;
        shellArgs = argc -1; 
    } else {
        bg = false;
        shellArgs = argc;
    }   

    // Save the linux commands in a new array
    char *executableCommands[shellArgs+1];
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < shellArgs+1; j++) {
        executableCommands[j] = args[j];
    }   
    executableCommands[shellArgs] = NULL;

    // Check the $PATH
    const char delimiters[] = ":";
    char *token, *cp;
    char *forLater;
    int count = 0;
    char *path;
    path = getenv("PATH");

    // All of this just breaks up the path into separate strings
    cp = strdup(path);    
    forLater = strdup(path);
    token = strtok (cp, delimiters); 
    while ((token = strtok (NULL, delimiters)) != NULL) {
        count++;
    }   
    char **argv;
    int size = count+1;
    argv = (char**) malloc (size);
    count = 0;
    token = strtok (forLater, delimiters); 
    argv[0] = (char*) malloc (50);
    argv[0] = token;
    strcpy(argv[0],token);
    while ((token = strtok (NULL, delimiters)) != NULL) {
        count++;
        argv[count] = (char*) malloc (50);
        argv[count] = token;
    }   

    // This goes through the path to see if the linux command they entered
    // Ex: sleep exists in one of those files and saves it to a var
    int i;
    bool weHaveIt = false;
    int ac; 
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        char str[80];
        strcpy(str, argv[i]);
        strcat(str, "/");
        strcat(str, args[0]);
        ac = access(str, F_OK);
        if (ac == 0) {
            weHaveIt = true;
            strcpy(pathToExecute, str);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!weHaveIt) {
        printf("That is not a valid command. SORRY!\n");
        return;
    }

    executableCommands[0] = pathToExecute;
    int status;

    // Get the array for 

    // If user wants command to be a background process
    if (bg) {
        int background_process_id;
        pid_t fork_return;
        fork_return = fork();

        if (fork_return == 0) {
            background_process_id = getpid();
            addJobToTable(strippedCommand, background_process_id);
            setpgid(0, 0);
            execve(executableCommands[0], executableCommands, NULL);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        int background_process_id;
        pid_t fork_return;
        fork_return = fork();

        if (fork_return == 0) {
            background_process_id = getpid();
            status = execve(executableCommands[0], executableCommands, NULL);
            exit(0);
        } else {
                wait(&status);
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `wait` made for the third job returns immediately because the second job has finished and is waiting to be handled (also called "zombie"). You could check the return value of `wait(&status)`, which is the PID of the process that has exited, and make sure it is the process you were waiting for. If it's not, just call `wait` again.

Alternatively use `waitpid`, which waits for a specific process:

```
/* Wait for child. was: wait(&status) */
waitpid(fork_return, &status, 0);
```

If you do this you should implement a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` to handle finished background jobs to prevent the accumulation of "zombie" child processes.

In addition to that, in the background job case, the branch where `fork()` returns 0 you are already in the new process, so the call to `addJobToTable` happens in the wrong process. Also, you should check the return values of all the calls; otherwise something may be failing and you don't know it. So the code for running a job in the background should look more like this:

```
    if (fork_return == 0) {
        setpgid(0, 0);
        if (execve(executableCommands[0], executableCommands, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("execve");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else if (fork_return != -1) {
        addJobToTable(strippedCommand, fork_return);
        return;
    } else {
        perror("fork"); /* fork failed */
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Great! This was really helpful. Thanks. Everything seems to be working good.

Answer (score 1):

Every child process created with `fork()` will exit when the parent process exits.

```
if (fork_return == 0) {
   /* child process, do stuff */
} else {
   /* parent process, exit immediately */
   return;
}
```

#### Explanation

[`fork`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) spawns a new process as a child process of the current process (parent). Whenever a process in Unix-like operating systems terminates all of its child processes are going to be terminated too. If they have child processes on their own, then these will get terminated too.

#### Solution

On most shells you can start a process in background if you add an ampersand `&` to the end of the line:

```
myApplication arg1 arg2 arg3 ... argN &
```

Comment: Erm, no. The child processes continue to run, and the parent of the process that just terminated becomes their new parent.